# JDBC SQL Server Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, minecraft

I am using a minecraft jdbc logging plugin (LogBlock), which automatically parses my inputs for server name, login, password, and port into a valid jdbc command. I have set up a server and user using Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014 and tested it with my login using [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steverac/archive/2010/12/14/test-remote-sql-connectivity-easily.aspx) and it told me that it succeded. I can only assume that it is an error in the parsing of my inputs. I would like to find a way to not have to change the source code of the plugin, but instead edit my inputs so that it will trick the plugin into parsing correctly. Here's the code that I give the plugin:

```
    mysql:
      host: BOB\SQLEXPRESS
      database: minecraft
      password: Testest12/345
      user: skrublord9000
      port: 3306
```

Bob is my computer name, SQLEXPRESS is the server name. I can't help but think it's the backwards slash that's causing the problem. Here's the output of the jdbc plugin:

```
    [LogBlock] Connecting to skrublord9000@jdbc:mysql://BOB\SQLEXPR
    ESS:3306/minecraft?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8...
    [LogBlock] Error while fetching connection:
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot loa
    d connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatExcep
    tion: For input string "3306/minecraft"'.
               at .........
```

and that last stack continues for many lines. (I'm putting in the code manually and I don't have time to write all that.)

I'm open to all questions, suggestions, and solutions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your connection string: ':3306/minecraft?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8' is for MySQL not for Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Logblock currently only supports MySQL.
See: http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/logblock/

> Everything is logged into a MySQL database

LogBlock is using a jdbc MySQL url to connect. That's why it's being parsed wrongly.

The only solution to this problem is to use a MySQL server instead of a Microsoft SQL Server.